# How to ingest .doc / .docx files in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, data-ingestion, elasticsearch-7, fscrawler

I'm trying to index word documents in my elasticsearch environment. I tried using the elasticsearch ingest-attachment plugin, but it seems like it's only possible to ingest base64 encoded data.

My goal is to index whole directories with word files. I tried using [FSCrawler](https://github.com/dadoonet/fscrawler) but it sadly currently contains a bug when indexing word documents. I would be really thankfull if someone could explain me a way to index directories containing word documents.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the bug you mentioned? May be link to the issue you opened?